# gl.h #defines for lights

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

Does this following technique:

```
for(int light=GL_LIGHT0; light<=GL_LIGHT7; light++)
    glEnable(light);
```

always enable `GL_LIGHT0` through `GL_LIGHT7` flawlessly? I'm wondering if the`#define`s for the OpenGL lights always increment by one, one after another as they do in my OpenGL header file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the reason for this?  What parameters are you setting to the lights after you enable them?

Comment: @TimCooper Some material properties from a .obj file exported from Blender. The reason this question came about is because the amount of lights I'm enabling is going to vary depending on the amount of lights in the file. I treat each material beginning with the word "light" as a new light, and any vertices using that material are averaged to get the location of the light. Blender light data doesn't actually export, that's why I do it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The OpenGL specification clearly states that

```
GL_LIGHT<n> == GL_LIGHT0 + n
```